# iOS loading Base 64 encoded data in webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, base64, nsdata

I am trying to load base64 encoded data in a webview.Following is the code i am using

```
NSDictionary *fileFormatDic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",@"html",@"mage/jpeg",@"jpe",@"image/jpeg",@"jpeg",@"image/jpeg",@"jpg",@"application/pdf",@"pdf",@"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",@"pdf",@"text/plain",@"txt",@"application/vnd.ms-excel",@"xls",@"application/msword",@"doc",nil];
NSData *fileData= [dbServiceMgr getDocumentDataForTheTaskId:[_fileDetailsDic objectForKey:@"taskId"] andFileId:[_fileDetailsDic objectForKey:@"fileId"]];
NSLog(@"filedata length---%d",fileData.length);

NSString *mimeType=[fileFormatDic objectForKey:[_fileDetailsDic objectForKey:@"fileFormat"]];

[_webView loadData:fileData MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName:@"Base64" baseURL:nil];
```

But nothing is displayed in my webview. Can someone tell me, what is going wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the reason for which you get a white screen (could be) but you must understand that `textEncodingName` expects a text encoding (meaning a method to encode a Unicode string to byte sequences) and you are providing a binary data-to-text encoding. So it's a different kind of encoding so to speak. Valid values would be UTF8 or UTF16 (althoulgh UTF8 is what you usually want). So, you should first decode your Base64 data and then present it to the screen.

You can read more about Unicode encodings [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Hi Valentin, thanks for your answer. i Solved the issue by decoding the fileData.